# Symfony FOSRestBundle Actions Order

Tags: php, rest, annotations, symfony, fosrestbundle

i get started a new proyect with symfony3 and FOSRestBundle for a REST API. Everything is working as expected, but i have a question. I have this two actions on my controller and the router config:

`api_marcas_get_all_marca_paginated   GET   ANY   ANY /api/marca/{limit}/{page}.{_format}`
`api_marcas_delete_remove_marca       GET   ANY   ANY /api/marca/delete/{marcaid}.{_format}`

The problem is that when i call this (from Postman):

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/marca/delete/105
```

The other action (api_marcas_get_all_marca_paginated) responds...

Yes.. i know that i can use the "DELETE" http method, and this is worked... but... Why do they collide?

Here are my actions:

```
 /**
 * @Rest\Get("/marca/{limit}/{page}")
 */
public function getAllMarcaPaginatedAction(Request $request)
{... code here ...}
```

and

```
 /**
 * @Rest\Get("/marca/delete/{marcaid}")
 */
public function deleteRemoveMarcaAction(Request $request)
{ ... //code here... }
```

On that order.

I am doing something wrong? 
Has anything to do with order of the actions? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because those rules are considered sequentially, and the first match is taken.

In your example `/api/marca/delete/105` the first rule matches as `delete` to be the `{limit}` and `105` to be the `{page}`.

You can define some requirements for the `{limit}` so to match only certain patterns. Here you can find some examples of how to use the `requirements` annotation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html

On the other side, it's the recommended practice not to use `GET` method for operations that alter the state of the application (like deleting an item), being considered a [safe method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: Thanks for comment @dubrox. Do you have any advise to avoid these kind of problems with the route?

Comment: I just updated my answer to suggest the use of the `requirements` attribute to avoid this pattern collision in general. But in your particular case you should really avoid `GET` for a deletion, and at least use the `POST` method if you really don't want to use the HTTP standard `DELETE`.